# Multiple separated development environments on Windows?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, npm, config

Since I develop on different projects which require different settings and different kinds of plugins with specific settings, is there any way I can use different idea.properties files without renaming them every time or duplicating the whole IDE?

For example I pass the specific config as parameter like 
idea64.exe -config="environtment1.properties" which leads to C:\project1\config
idea64.exe -config="environtment2.properties" which leads to C:\project2\config

Is something similar possible with NPM? Because I often encounter problems which are caused from other packages which I don't even use, or I need different versions of the package for each project, so it would be great if I could start with a completely fresh environment every time I create a new workspace.

The only thing I could think of are virtual machines, but that wouldn't be very performant and each VM would create overhead and setting up a new VM, even from a snapshot is crazly annyoing... But that would be a way to separate each project.

Second thing would be duplicating the applications which I already mentioned, but this would take about 1GB and more per project only for the apps.

I can't come up with a clean solution, I'd like to set different config folders per app but if the software doesn't support passing a new config path through a parameter I'm pretty much screwed.

Someone got an idea how to solve my first world problems?

Comment: Can you run wrapper scripts that set environment variables, and access them via your build / config in intellij? For example maven can access `system` environment variables, i'm not sure if you can do something similar.

Comment: Good question, I'm also not sure if something like that is possible, but I'm sure I can't use npm this way.. :/

I just remember I've read that Docker is also available for Windows, I wonder if that'd be possible with Docker?

Comment: Could you please split this into separate questions for IntelliJ IDEA and npm? There are really two completely independent questions.

Comment: Well the main question is to separate development environments, so I don't see any point in splitting because the answer for my problem should be a solution for EVERY software, like using VMs.

Comment: I think I've found a way, I'll use Windows VHDs which I'll mount to a specific folder and then I place the config folders and npm repositories etc. into that folder so I can switch between different VHDs for every environment. So it is also portable and the software can use all resources, because using Docker with Vagrant would be a convenient way, but since Docker runs in a VM the performance of the IDE within a VM would be pretty bad since my workstation doesn't have the best hardware..

Comment: I can't speak to the IntelliJ issues, but `npm` should only be installing the "correct" packages, that is, the actual dependencies, for each project in the `node_modules` directory, so you should not be seeing conflicts there...

Are you having conflicts between *globally* installed `npm` modules?